# Мини чат для простенькго сайта: AJAX или WebSocket?

Tags: ajax, websocket, чат

Хочу сделать чатик. Проект небольшой, нагрузок особых не будет. Что лучше использовать, вебсокеты или аякс?

Склоняюсь к ajax из-за простоты реализации, разрешите?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше конечно использовать websocket, но для небольшого проекта можно еще использовать Server-Sent Events чем Ajax.